Need Help Proving a Functor Preserves Limits
I am doing an exercise about proving that the forgetful functor $Sup \rightarrow Pos$ has a left adjoint.
(Here Sup is the category of partially ordered sets with supremum and Pos is just the category of partially ordered sets.) I have verified all of the conditions to apply the Special Adjoint Functor Theorem, except for one: that this functor preserves limits.
We need to prove that there can't be more supremums in $Pos$ than in $Sup$, right? If so, is there any quick way of concluding so?
Thanks!

Given $X\in\mathrm{Sup}$, I will write $|X|$ for the underlying poset.
You need to show that, given a diagram $\mathcal{I}\to\mathsf{Sup}, i\mapsto X_i$, we have $|\mathrm{lim}_i\,X_i|\cong\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|$. This can be done by showing that the poset $\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|$ has suprema, and that the structure maps $\pi_i\colon\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|\to X_i$ preserve these suprema. Why? Because $\mathsf{Sup}$ is a subcategory of $\mathsf{Pos}$, so it is then a general fact that a limit in $\mathsf{Pos}$ of a diagram fully contained in $\mathsf{Sup}$ will also be a limit in $\mathsf{Sup}$ precisely when the limiting object and the structure maps (the $\pi_i$) are contained in $\mathsf{Sup}$.
We see as follows that $\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|$ has suprema: an element $x$ of it corresponds to a system $(x_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ of elements $x_i\in X_i$. So, given a collection of elements $x^k\in\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|$, corresponding to $(x^k_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$, we let $\mathrm{sup}_k\,x^k$ be the element corresponding to the system $(\mathrm{sup}_k\,x^k_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$. This of course needs some checking that this actually works, but I will leave that to you. Moreover, from this description of the suprema, it is immediate that $\pi_i\colon\mathrm{lim}_i|X_i|\to X_i$ preserve these suprema. With that, you would be done: we now know that $|-|\colon\mathsf{Sup}\to\mathsf{Pos}$ preserves limits.
There is (of course) a more general statement in the background here: under the inclusion of $\mathsf{Pos}$ into $\mathsf{Cat}$, the $1$-category of small categories, and under the inclusion of $\mathsf{Sup}$ into $\mathsf{Cat}^\mathrm{cc}$ of cocomplete small $1$-categories (which are already posets) and cocontinuous functors, we have secretly used a special case of the following statement: if $\mathcal{I}\to\mathsf{Cat}, i\mapsto \mathcal{C}_i$ is a system of categories, and $x, y\in\mathrm{lim}_i\,\mathcal{C}_i$ are objects corresponding to $(x_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ and $(y_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ (with $x_i,y_i\in\mathcal{C}_i$), then
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,\mathcal{C}_i}(x,y)\cong\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}_i}(x_i,y_i).
$$
If all functors $\mathcal{C}_i\to\mathcal{C}_j$ in our system preserve colimits, then this allows you to conclude that colimits in $\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\mathcal{C}_i$ are computed ''componentwise'' in all the categories $\mathcal{C}_i$, because the universal property of colimits only talks about hom-sets. Since suprema in posets are colimits, this explains where our formula above came from (and why it works: if you're comfortable with this statement about hom-sets, you don't have to verify that our suprema formula for $\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}|X_i|$ above actually works).
